# File 'numArEx.txt' loading forever

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, image-processing

I was testing a code that I see in Internet, but I'm having some problems. I'd like receive a answer about why my archive does not open correctly, it stay loading and loading and I dont can view what happened with then. The correctly would be have many numbers between 0 and 255 (RGB color). I'm thinking the problem is in the funtion 'np.seterr(over='ignore')' but if excluse this, then I have another problem, so, I dont know. The code do: identifies images from a database. Thanks in advance.

CODE:

```
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
from collections import Counter

np.seterr(over='ignore')

def createExamples():
    numberArrayExamples=open('numArEx.txt','a')
    numbersWeHave=range(1,3)
    versionsWeHave=range(1,10)

    for eachNum in numbersWeHave:
        for eachVer in versionsWeHave:
        #print str(eachNum)+'.'+str(eachVer)
        imgFilePath = 'images/'+str(eachNum)+'.'+str(eachVer)+'.jpg'
        ei=Image.open(open(imgFilePath,'rb'))
        eiar=np.array(ei)
        eiar1=str(eiar.tolist())

        lineToWrite=str(eachNum)+'::'+eiar1+'\n'
        numberArrayExamples.write(lineToWrite)

def threshold(imageArray):
    balanceAr = []
    newAr = imageArray
    for eachRow in imageArray:
        for eachPix in eachRow:
            avgNum = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, eachPix[:3]) / eachPix[:3])
            balanceAr.append(avgNum)
    balance = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, balanceAr) / len(balanceAr)
    for eachRow in newAr:
        for eachPix in eachRow:
            if reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, eachPix[:3]) / eachPix[:3]) > balance:
                eachPix[0] = 255
                eachPix[1] = 255
                eachPix[2] = 255
            else:
                eachPix[0] = 0
                eachPix[1] = 0
                eachPix[2] = 0
    return newAr

def whatNumIsThis(filePath):
    matchedAr=[]
    loadExamps=open('numArEx.txt','r').read()
    loadExamps=loadExamps.split('\n')

    i=Image.open(open(filePath,'rb'))
    iar=np.array(i)
    iar1=iar.tolist()

    inQuestion=str(iar1)

    for eachExample in loadExamps:
        try:
            splitEx=eachExample.split('::')
            currentNum=splitEx[0]
            currentAr=splitEx[1]
            eachPixEx = currentAr.split(']')
            eachPixInQ=inQuestion.split(']')
            x=0
            while x<len(eachPixEx):
                if eachPixEx[x]==eachPixInQ[x]:
                    matchedAr.append(int(currentNum))
                x+=1
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

    print matchedAr
    x=Counter(matchedAr)
    print (x)
    print (x[0])

whatNumIsThis('images/teste.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've based your code on the project [here](https://github.com/saravrajavelu/Image-Recognition)

It's hard to tell exactly what has broken, as I don't have access to the JPEG files you are using (the original project uses PNG files).

However, the following version of your code does work with the PNG files supplied in the GitHub project, stored in the same directory structure you can see there (in images/numbers). I have removed the `threshold()` function as it was not being called.

Hopefully you can use this as a starting point to work from.

```
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
from collections import Counter

def createExamples():
    numberArrayExamples=open('numArEx.txt','w')  # replace, do not append
    numbersWeHave=range(1,3)
    versionsWeHave=range(1,10)

    for eachNum in numbersWeHave:
        for eachVer in versionsWeHave:
            #print str(eachNum)+'.'+str(eachVer)
            imgFilePath = 'images/numbers/'+str(eachNum)+'.'+str(eachVer)+'.png'
            ei=Image.open(open(imgFilePath,'rb'))
            eiar=np.array(ei)
            eiar1=str(eiar.tolist())

            lineToWrite=str(eachNum)+'::'+eiar1+'\n'
            numberArrayExamples.write(lineToWrite)
    numberArrayExamples.close()

def whatNumIsThis(filePath):
    matchedAr=[]
    loadExamps=open('numArEx.txt','r').read()
    loadExamps=loadExamps.split('\n')

    i=Image.open(open(filePath,'rb'))
    iar=np.array(i)
    iar1=iar.tolist()

    inQuestion=str(iar1)

    for eachExample in loadExamps:
        if len(eachExample) > 3:
            splitEx=eachExample.split('::')
            currentNum=splitEx[0]
            currentAr=splitEx[1]
            eachPixEx = currentAr.split(']')
            eachPixInQ=inQuestion.split(']')
            x = 0
            while x<len(eachPixEx):
                if eachPixEx[x]==eachPixInQ[x]:
                    matchedAr.append(int(currentNum))
                x+=1

    print (matchedAr)
    x=Counter(matchedAr)
    print (x)

createExamples()
whatNumIsThis('images/test.png')
whatNumIsThis('images/test1.png')
```

Comment: @GhostCat OK I was intending for the OP to edit his/her question, not for someone else to try to edit. I guess I misundertsood the effect of "Requires Editing"; I assumed it would be flagged back to the OP, not just go into a queue.  In future I'll just add a comment along the lines of "please could you make the question clearer?". Peace, AS.